# Instagram APIs vs WebKit View

Tags: ios, swift, instagram-api

I built a brand new iOS repost App from scratch to manage our accounts. At the moment it uses webkit view to handle the data such as thumbnails, title, hashtags etc. I was wondering if Meta offers public API integration for 3rd party apps? I think if I could build it with APIs it would be much more reliable and quicker. For example, this app https://apps.apple.com/us/app/repost-for-instagram/id1477820240 is extremely fast, which means it may be using APIs?

I tired to look up some old posts but all says they don't provide any APIs, or if they do its pretty basic

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram/